# Fading in/out of 2 forms parallel in Delphi with Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, fadein, fadeout

I have a Delphi 10.4.2 FMX application running on Windows 10 with 2 forms in which images are moving. Both are on top of each other. I want to slowly fade out of form 1 and fade in form 2 at the same time. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry to say, but FMX forms do not have a `Opacity` property that would make this possible.

Comment: However, a `TFrame` has that `Opacity` property, so if you can do with ONE form and two frames (each holding the components you were considering for the two forms). Then you could have one form but two different interiors, that you can fade between. I have not done this before, but edit your question and include the `.pas` and `.fmx` files of the forms, so I can try something.

Comment: There are too much lines of code to include. I had to build a simple example. I try to use two TScaledLayout and make only one of them visible. It is functioning but also a lot of work. Parallel I try to use Remy Lebeau's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An FMX Form does not natively support what you are asking for.

However, when run on Windows, a Form does have a Win32 `HWND` assigned to it  (which you can obtain using `FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND()`). As such, you can use the Win32 API `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` function to manually assign a translucency value to the window.

Comment: For SetLayeredWindowAttributes() to work, the form must have Transparency set to true and Fill.Color must contain a TColorAnimation. For fadein ok, but for fadeout a new TColorAnimation has to be assigned. How does it work in the program?

Comment: TColorAnimation sets translucency only for the form not for the objects. SetLayeredWindowAttributes stops current onTimer activities. So moving images stop. Any explanation?

Comment: @PeterKloß "*SetLayeredWindowAttributes stops current onTimer activities*" - it shouldn't have any effect on timers. Unless you are using a window-based timer, and the window is being destroyed while applying the attributes.

Comment: Please try my sample program. The moving of Label1 stops after pressing Button1.     You can find the sources at https://kloss.solutions/public/FadeInOut/

Comment: @PeterKloß I can't try it (no Delphi installed right now) so I can't comment on why it stops working, but I will say that using `Application.ProcessMessages()` in a blocking loop as you are is not the best approach to handle what you are doing. It's dangerous enough in VCL, more so in FMX. I would instead suggest breaking out the loop and reuse `TTimer1`, or use [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) with a delay specified. Don't *ever* block the main UI thread for anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do.  In the code below, I have created two forms, each with Transparency set to True.
Each has a TLayout on it aligned by client.
Each TLayout has a TImageControl.  I chose TImageControl only because it has a LoadFromFile method which make this demonstration easy.  You could use a different image control instead.  (TImageControl does have a border which you mightn't want to see.)
The reason for the TLayouts is because I want an OnClick handler for the demo, but clicking on a TImageControl opens an open file dialog.  So I had to set HitTest to False on the TImageControl, and have the TLayouts to handle the mouse clicks.  With a different image control you should be able to do without the TLayouts.

The first form has a TFloatAnimation linked to the TLayout's Opacity property.  That TFloatAnimation's OnProgress event updates the opacity of the TLayout on the other form.

Clicking a form triggers the fade out/fade in.  Double-clicking closes the application.  (There needs to be some way to close it as a transparent form doesn't have the normal close button.)

**Form1 .fmx**:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form6'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 680
  Transparency = True
  Visible = True
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Layout1: TLayout
    Align = Client
    HitTest = True
    Size.Width = 680.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Layout1Click
    OnDblClick = Layout1DblClick
    object ImageControl1: TImageControl
      Align = Client
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 680.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object FloatAnimation1: TFloatAnimation
      Duration = 2.000000000000000000
      OnProcess = FloatAnimation1Process
      OnFinish = FloatAnimation1Finish
      PropertyName = 'Opacity'
      StartValue = 1.000000000000000000
      StopValue = 0.000000000000000000
    end
  end
end
```

**Form2 .fmx**

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form7'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 680
  Transparency = True
  Visible = True
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Layout1: TLayout
    Align = Client
    HitTest = True
    Opacity = 0.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 680.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Layoutl1Click
    OnDblClick = Layout1DblClick
    object ImageControl1: TImageControl
      Align = Client
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 680.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end
```

**Form1 code**:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Effects,
  FMX.Filter.Effects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Ani, FMX.Layouts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ImageControl1: TImageControl;
    FloatAnimation1: TFloatAnimation;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    procedure Layout1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FloatAnimation1Process(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Layout1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FloatAnimation1Finish(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses  FormTwo;

procedure TForm1.FloatAnimation1Finish(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FloatAnimation1.Inverse:=not FloatAnimation1.Inverse;
end;

procedure TForm1.FloatAnimation1Process(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Form2) then Form2.Layout1.Opacity:=1-Layout1.Opacity;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImageControl1.LoadFromFile({your image path here});
end;

procedure TForm1.Layout1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FloatAnimation1.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Layout1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

end.
```

**Form2 code**:

```
unit FormTwo;

interface

uses
  MainForm,
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Layouts;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ImageControl1: TImageControl;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Layoutl1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Layout1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Top:=Form1.Top;
  Left:=Form1.Left;
  IMageControl1.LoadFromFile({your image path here});
end;

procedure TForm2.Layoutl1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.FloatAnimation1.Start;
end;

procedure TForm2.Layout1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

end.
```